# Firebase messaging subscribe to topics after token refresh and multiple devices sync

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-admin-sdk

From my testing and understanding,

1. I noticed that when a user subscribes to a topic using Device A, and logs in on Device B.
   **Device B will not receive that topic's notification unless the user subscribes to that topic from Device B as well.** How can i have both devices receive the notification when only one device subscribes?
2. When using the FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen() stream, and the users token changes, **how can i subscribe his new token to his previously subscribed topics**? (Note: I store them in the database).

Comment: 1. <User> logs in on Device B should be used as a trigger to syncronize of topic subscription.

Comment: How can i make a token subscribe to a topic? Or do you mean i should  just make the user subscribe to the topics in the database after every login and disregard duplicate requests? @AlexMounir